# PyQT autoupdate Label

Tags: python, pyqt

The Labels

```
self.titlelabel = QLabel(self)
self.artistlabel = QLabel(self)
self.albumlabel = QLabel(self)
```

in the UI do not update, when i run the method. 
I mean, they do work on the initial initialization of the `initUI(self)`, but when i change the item in the combobox, the do not update with the new information
I run this command in the `initUI(self)` which is connected to the dropdown /Qcombobox `self.cb.activated.connect(self.updateTrackInfo)`

```
def currentTrackInfo(self):
    currentTrackInfoDict = {}
    currentZone = str(self.cb.currentText())
    deviceDict = self.sonosZonesCoordinatorsIP()
    for key, value in deviceDict.items():
        if value == currentZone:
            device = SoCo(key)
            track = device.get_current_track_info()
            current_title = track['title']
            current_artist  = track["artist"]
            current_album = track["album"]

    currentTrackInfoDict.update({"current_title":current_title})
    currentTrackInfoDict.update({"current_artist":current_artist})
    currentTrackInfoDict.update({"current_album":current_album})

    return currentTrackInfoDict

def updateTrackInfo(self):
    self.currentTrackInfoDict = self.currentTrackInfo()

    self.titlelabel = QLabel(self)
    self.artistlabel = QLabel(self)
    self.albumlabel = QLabel(self)

    self.titlelabel.move((PLAYICONHEIGHT-100),(WINDOWHEIGHT-230))
    self.artistlabel.move((PLAYICONHEIGHT-100),(WINDOWHEIGHT-220))
    self.albumlabel.move((PLAYICONHEIGHT-100),(WINDOWHEIGHT-250))

    self.titlelabel.setText("Title: {}".format(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_title"]))
    print(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_title"])
    self.artistlabel.setText("Artist: {}".format(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_artist"]))
    self.albumlabel.setText("Album: {}".format(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_album"]))
```

The print function : `print(self.currentTrackInfoDict["current_title"])` - works, but the labels are not being updated.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your `updateTrackInfo` method each time you create the new `QLabel` objects instead of just updating the text on the existing ones. It may cause a problems since the new labels overlap with old (you are not deleting the old labels and they still exist after `updateTrackInfo` is called). I would suggest to move

   ```
   self.titlelabel = QLabel(self)
   self.artistlabel = QLabel(self)
   self.albumlabel = QLabel(self)

   self.titlelabel.move((PLAYICONHEIGHT-100),(WINDOWHEIGHT-230))
   self.artistlabel.move((PLAYICONHEIGHT-100),(WINDOWHEIGHT-220))
   self.albumlabel.move((PLAYICONHEIGHT-100),(WINDOWHEIGHT-250))
   ```

into the `__init__(self)` method and keep only the labels updating code in your `updateTrackInfo` method

2. I would suggest to use `currentIndexChanged` `QComboBox` signal instead of `activated`

Comment: Perfect !!

And thank you for explaining me the reasons. Makes perfectly sense and it works !

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: A better option is `currentTextChanged`